# Minimum spanning tree formulation

Tags: integer-programming, minimum-spanning-tree

Can any expert explain the reasoning behind the constraint in the
following formulation of the minimum spanning tree?

> To formulate the minimum-cost spanning tree (MST) problem as an LP, we associate a variable $x_e$ with every edge $e \in E$. Each spanning tree $T$ corresponds to its *incidence vector* $x^T$, which is defined by $x^T_e = 1$ if $T$ contains $e$ and $x^T_e = 0$ otherwise. Let $\Pi$ denote the set of all partitions of the vertex set $V$, and suppose that $\pi \in \Pi$. The *rank* $r(\pi)$ of $\pi$ is the number of parts of $\pi$. Let $E_\pi$ denote the set of edges whose ends lie in different parts of $\pi$. Consider the following LP:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \min &\sum_{e \in E} c_ex_e \\
> \text{s.t. } &\sum_{e \in E_\pi} x_e \geq r(\pi) - 1 \quad \forall \pi \in \Pi, \\
> & x \geq 0. \\
> \end{align*}
> $$

Comment: As I suggested [the last time you asked a similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/119580/755), I suggest working through a small example by hand, and see what happens if you include that constraint and what happens if you leave it out.

Comment: I tried but still not clear.

Comment: Cool, why don't you share with us a summary of what you've come up with and show some examples that illustrate why this is interesting/unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The constraint expresses the following fact:

> Let $T$ be a spanning tree, and suppose that we partition the vertex set into $r$ parts. There are exactly $r-1$ edges of $T$ which connect different parts.

For example, if $T$ is a tree and $C,\overline{C}$ is a cut, then exactly one edge of $T$ crosses the cut, that is, connects $C$ and $\overline{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question was the reasoning behind the constraint, not what it means. Ie, my question was why such a constraint should hold.

Comment: Well, that's a nice exercise.